# Embedding transparent png onto an image is too slow

Tags: php, image, png, watermark, gdlib

The function below embeds a watermark onto an image. In some servers it's super slow while I never encounter the same issue in my server. What could be wrong with it? I'm out of ideas.

```
function add_watermark( $source_file_path, $output_file_path, $watermark_file_path, $quality = 80 ) {
    list( $source_width, $source_height, $source_type ) = getimagesize( $source_file_path );

    if ( $source_type === NULL ) {
        return false;
    }

    switch ( $source_type ) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromgif( $source_file_path );
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromjpeg( $source_file_path );
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng( $source_file_path );
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    $overlay_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng( $watermark_file_path );
    $overlay_width = imagesx( $overlay_gd_image );
    $overlay_height = imagesy( $overlay_gd_image );

    imagecopy(
        $source_gd_image,
        $overlay_gd_image,
        $source_width - $overlay_width - 10,
        $source_height - $overlay_height - 10,
        0,
        0,
        $overlay_width,
        $overlay_height
    );

    imagejpeg( $source_gd_image, $output_file_path, $quality );
    imagedestroy( $source_gd_image );
    imagedestroy( $overlay_gd_image );
}
```

I'm not sure if it has something to do with php.ini configs but here's the configs that's used in all servers:

```
memory_limit = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 192M
post_max_size = 100M
file_uploads = On
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Comment: It clearly depends on input and performance of server. It's subjective.

Comment: @webarto: If I switch to ImageMagick, would that help? I suspect GD is the other issue here.

Comment: I'm sure it would be faster/less memory consuming, but probably at the price of portability (if that matters), since GD is more or less inbuilt. Code itself doesn't look like a problem.